# PHP XML Array Slice and Reverse or Reverse then Array Slice

Tags: php, arrays, slice, reverse

Have an xml file ... the webpage shows the most recent 50 new nodes. When you click a link 'show more' it adds a ?node= to the url which I $_get to change the slice starting point ($start_node) ... but it doesn't. The value DOES change but the slice doesn't work. Por que?!

```
$master = array_slice($xml_get->xpath('unit'), $start_node);
$master = array_reverse($master);

$i = 0;

foreach ($master as $arc) {

    $last_data = $arc[0]->data;
    $last_link = $arc[0]->link;

    // doing stuff with values

    $i++;
    if ($i >= 50) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did people down vote this?! The learning here for others since it is not any where else is that slice then reverse not reverse then slice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't use the third parameter of [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) which is the number of elements to extract, you will retrieve all entries from the start node on.  When you reverse this and extract the first 50, this will always be the last 50 of all of the nodes.

So to extract from `$start_node` to `$start_node`+50...

```
$master = array_slice($xml_get->xpath('unit'), $start_node, 50);
$master = array_reverse($master);
foreach($master as $arc) {
    $last_data  = $arc[0]->data;
    $last_link  = $arc[0]->link;

    // doing stuff with values
}
```

Comment: Had it this way before going to the $i++ version but I had reverse first and then slice before since flipping them which I figure now why it didn't work. Thx!